# Problem accessing Azure SQL database table from iOS swift app

Tags: ios, swift, azure, azure-sql-database

I created a demo app that authenticates user from Azure Active Directory and able to perform sync with easy tables. When I connected App Service at Azure Portal with SQL database then fetching a table data in iOS swift app throws 401 error. Below is the code snippet.

```
let client = MSClient(applicationURLString: "URL String")

        let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!

        self.store = MSCoreDataStore(managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

        client.syncContext = MSSyncContext(delegate: nil, dataSource: self.store, callback: nil)

        self.table = client.syncTable(withName: "table name")

        self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ActivityTableViewController.onRefresh(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
```

API call (onRefresh call):

```
self.table!.pull(with: self.table?.query(), queryId: "AllRecords") {

            (error) -> Void in DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                // throws 401 error here
            }
        }
```

Now I have bypassed the user authentication and in Azure App Service, easy table is working fine and I can access data from mobile app.

I connected SQL database with App Service and created a easy table with same name as I have in SQL database. It created the same schema in easy table as I have in SQL database. Now the problem is that I am not able to fetch data in mobile app from this table. SQL database has entries in table.

Comment: can you verify formatting? i think i messed something up

Comment: Responded to your MSDN post: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/df675f1f-584c-4ed0-8087-7d483e745d89/problem-accessing-azure-sql-database-table-from-ios-swift-app?forum=ssdsgetstarted